# azure devops , restrict permission to add reviewers in PR

Tags: azure, azure-devops, branch

we have branch the master , I added in branch policy approvers and must 1 to approve.

and i added 2 names in "Automatically included reviewers"

now I want to restrict from developers to add approvers and only who is in "Automatically included reviewers" list , can approve.

Comment: Any reason you wouldn't care if someone else approved as long as the 2 auto approvers are required?  I would think you would handle that by creating a group, adding the two reviewers, then requiring the group.  Others can approve, but the policy would force at least one from the group approval.

Comment: is can change the group , but is only 2 person

the target is to block permission from developers are not team leader or mangers to add reviewers to pr and then to accept them own prs.